# delete repeated line in vim, keep the n-th line in Vim

Tags: regular-expression, normal-mode

I want to ask how to delete repeated lines in vim.
For now, I have a file which contained 12740 lines. There are only 98 unique lines, and each line is duplicated 129 times.

I have tried:

```
g/^\(.*\)$\n\1$/d
```

But my problem is, some unique lines are the same to each other, I don't know which lines are those.

When I input that command, my file becomes 95 lines, not 98 which I want. (3 lines are the same to each other, I guess, so it's also deleted).
Any other solution?
I'll edit if my question is still not clear enough.

My file:
`-0.00697568` - line 1
`-0.00697568` - line 2
`...`
`0.00697568`  - line 131
`0.00697568`  - line 132
`0.00697568`  - line 133
`...`
`0.020909881` - line 261
`0.020909881` - line 262
`...`
  And so on.
I need to keep the 130n+1 line, from n=0 until n=97.

**Edit** I need the lines to keep their order so a solution sorting the lines would not be an acceptable one.

Comment: If some "unique" lines are the same, how are they unique? O.o What makes them unique?

Comment: It's quite complex (as in O(N²)) to delete duplicates when the file is not sorted. In the case your file is sorted, or can be sorted, your question becomes a duplicate of this one: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5362/delete-all-consecutive-duplicates/5363#5363

Comment: @muru I think I can say it is like a 2-dimensional array: 98x130. I need to keep 98 lines and delete the other 129 lines, some of the line is the same to each other (but I still need to keep it 98).

Comment: @LucHermitte Yes you might be right, but unfortunately I must not sort it.

Comment: So, can you say you have to keep every 130th line? (Keep 1, delete 2-130, keep 131, delete 132-270, etc.)?

Comment: @muru indeed, that is I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @v8areu: You should rephrase your question to indicate that clearly: it is much easier to do that :-) Something like: `qaq` then `qa129dd@aq` then `@a` should do the trick.

Comment: Just to be sure. Are your duplicated lines grouped together, or can they be scattered? i.e. Do you need to reduce "1,2,3,1,5,8,2" to "1,2,3,5,8"?

Comment: The last edit let me think you're not in the case I've presented in my last comment. I deduce you are looking for an emulation of uniq, and thus, your question is a duplicate of http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5362/delete-all-consecutive-duplicates/5363 Do you confirm my analysis?

Comment: @LucHermitte on second thought, it might not be: it seems they want to reduce "1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5" to "1,2,3,3,5" (not "1,2,3,5" as `uniq` would have done).

Comment: @muru, that's the conclusion I've came to as well. uniq is not the solution then.

Comment: @statox I just learn about that cryptic recursive command and I guess I can do qqj129dd@qq@q and it's prettier since I will see the command repeated on screen (not on background!)  :D

Thanks for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To delete *n* lines starting from every line, you can do:

```
:%norm ndd
```

For example, if I started with the numbers 1 to 10 repeated 5 times:

```
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
6
6
6
6
6
7
7
7
7
7
8
8
8
8
8
9
9
9
9
9
10
10
10
10
10
```

And I do:

```
:%norm 4dd
```

I get:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

So, try `:%norm 129dd`.

This is one of those instances where you *want* `:%` instead of `:g`. `:g` tags the lines so that modifications while running the `g` command aren't counted for running the remaining iterations. `%`, on the other hand, will run from every line from 1 to the end, and it will only look at the current line numbers at each iteration.

Comment: If the file is really organized this way, it'd be safer to use one of the `uniq` emulation: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5362/delete-all-consecutive-duplicates/5363, no need to detect/count the number of replications.

Comment: @LucHermitte yes, it's just re-implementing plain ol' `uniq` in Vim. I suppose it's a matter of how the question should have been phrased: remove duplicates, or keep every *n*th line?

Comment: I've missed the fact that the OP observes that too many lines are removed when he applied uniq. I guess he has duplicated series of lines he wish to keep. In other word, he seems to be looking for "keep one line every _n_" and not uniq. My mistake. You're answering his needs.

Comment: I just know the %norm command can do the trick just fine, the other answer is also right, but this answer is neater. Thanks guys.

Comment: I don't get the last paragraph of this answer.  Wouldn't `:g/^/norm 129dd` do exactly the same thing as `:%norm 129dd`?

Comment: @Wildcard no. (Try it, you'll get an empty buffer.) `g` works by tagging every line that matches, and then running the command on only those lines, irrespective of whether those lines were modified, displaced or deleted by the command. `%` just runs from the first line to the last. So, in this case, `g/^/ norm 4dd`, for example, would delete lines 1, 2, 3, 4 while at the first line, then move to the now-deleted second line, and delete lines 2, 3, 4, 5 (instead of moving to 5, and deleting 5, 6, 7, 8). See http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3967/205. Compare: `g/\%<8l/ norm 2dd` and `1,7 norm 2dd`.

Comment: Oh, I think I see.  But it's not true that `g` runs on lines that were already deleted, only that it runs on the next marked line still existing even when that line now has a line number lower than the last line that was run (unlike `%` which will run on the next consecutive line number according to the *new* numbering).  For example, `g/^/+,+2d` will only delete 2 out of every 3 lines—it doesn't run on deleted lines.

Comment: In other words, `g/^/ norm 4dd` *doesn't* move to the now-deleted second line as you say—it's even mentioned in the answer you just linked to: "If a line is deleted its mark disappears."

Comment: @Wildcard you're right. I thought I saw some behaviour that would have been explained by it moving to a deleted line, but it looks like I was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I usually solve problems like this with a macro.  Position yourself at the top of your file, then start recording with <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.  The first "q" starts the recording.  The second "q" doesn't have to be "q".  It can be any register letter, I just use "q" because it's convenient.

Press <kbd>j</kbd> to go to the second line, then <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to delete all the duplicates.  Then press <kbd>q</kbd> to stop recording the macro.

Now you've taught vim how to do the operation once, and stored it in the `q` macro.  You just have to replay the macro 97 more times, by typing <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

I really like macros for this sort of problem, because it's relatively easy to *do* the action once manually, even if it's difficult to precisely *describe* how you do it in an easily repeatable manner.  I can just record myself and let vim do the repetitious work.

Answer (score 3):

Let's get the exact number of unique lines first.

```
 :sort u | echo line('$')
```

This command returns the total unique lines. 
In your case, this might be 95.

Let's do that with a macro.
Empty register `n` first. Press `qnq`.

1. Start recording by pressing `qn`. (n is the register name I have chosen)

   ```
   qn
   ```
2. Go to first line.

   ```
   :1
   ```
3. Press `Y` (same as y$) to copy till end of line

   ```
   Y
   ```
4. Type `:g/` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and `"`. The line is pasted as search pattern. Then, type `d`.

   ```
   :g/Ctrl+R"/d
   ```
5. All similar lines will be deleted including that one. Clear K register by pressing qkq. Now, let's copy the line to K register.

   ```
   :let @K="@/\n"
   ```
6. Press `q` to stop recording.

   ```
   q
   ```
7. Now, you can press count and `@n`. (We have obtained the count in the beginning through sort u and echo commands.)

   ```
   98@n
   ```
8. File will be emptied and all the contents will be stored in @K. Go to insert mode and type Ctrl+R and k. The contents of register is inserted there.
     i
     Ctrl+R k
   Now, the unique lines are pasted in file itself.

Edit: Recursive mapping is difficult for me to work with. This answer also gives what the user wanted.

Comment: the 5th phase, I think my similar lines is not deleted according to your answer. Or perhaps I do things wrongly? This is my first time using macro though, I would be very glad if you can edit the answer to become more "newbie-friendly"

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but it could be improved: as you don't provide an end condition the macro will loop indefinitely (It is of course possible to stop it with `ctrl-c`. Also it changes the order of the lines (the last one becomes the first one).

Comment: Don't know how to stop looping macro with a condition (without using a function). So, editing answer by getting the unique lines from :sort u command and then proceeding macro.

Comment: @SibiCoder I think I prefer: ggqqj129dd@qq@q will do just as same as you do. I just managed to learn about this kind of stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

An elegant one which shows the power of g command:

```
:g/\v^(\-?\d\.\d+)(\r?\n\1)+$/d
```

Just replace the pattern in the first parentheses to meet your other needs. It works even if the duplicated lines are not of the same number. And the order will be preserved also.

Comment: wow, I never think of this, great addition!