# In Vim, how can you delete following identical rows in a visual selection, without sorting?

Tags: ex-mode, replace, sort

So Lets say I have a list

```
\Summit
\SummitSign
\sun
\ProgrammingOnABoat
\SunCloud
\SunshineOpenCircled
\sup
\supdsub
\supdsub
\supedot
\suphsol
\suphsub
\Summit
\SummitSign
\sun
\Summit
\boatProgramming
\sup
```

I do not want to sort the list, I just want to remove identical rows, leaving only the first, like so:

```
\Summit
\SummitSign
\sun
\ProgrammingOnABoat
\SunCloud
\SunshineOpenCircled
\sup
\supdsub

\supedot
\suphsol
\suphsub




\boatProgramming
```

or like so:

```
\Summit
\SummitSign
\sun
\ProgrammingOnABoat
\SunCloud
\SunshineOpenCircled
\sup
\supdsub
\supedot
\suphsol
\suphsub
\boatProgramming
```

As you can see, it was not sorted, but the latter entries were removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete repeated line in vim, keep the n-th line in Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7879/delete-repeated-line-in-vim-keep-the-n-th-line-in-vim)

Comment: Actually, this question differ from the one you propose in the sens that this one does not have contiguous duplicates. Seeing the accepted answer on the question, it could not work for this case. (but the other way around would ;) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care about removing the first occurrence (leaving the last one), you can use the following global command:

```
g/^\(.*\)\n\_.*\(^\1$\)/d
```

Decomposing:

```
g/                     /d   " the global command will delete matched lines
  ^\(.*\)                   " Match anything from start of the line (create a group)
         \n                 " Match the end of the line
           \_.*             " Match any character (with new line) 0 or more time
               \(^\1$\)     " Match the previously matched group
```

This will find any line that has a duplicate later in the file and delete it.

It will delete duplicate lines but keeping only the last one.

---

As a workaround for the seek of keeping only the first occurence, you can use

```
 g/^/move 0
```

Before and after the substitution, this will reverse the order of the file, thus keeping the first line.

Comment: Awesome effort. Who knew regex could be readable?